# Fast Fourier Transform in R

Tags: r, time-series, fft, period, spectral-density

I have a dataset with the number of hourly visits an animal made during a period of 12 months. I want to use the Fast Fourier Transform to examine cyclical patterns and periodicity. In the past, I have used Statistica for this this; however, I would like to use R to get a plot of the spectral density vs. period. Is there an easy way to do this in R? I would like to identify 12 and 24 hr peak in activity if possible.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You may consider the following functions.

- `periodogram` from `TSA` package immediately plots a periodogram.
- `periodogram` from `GeneCycle` returns a list of frequencies and estimated power spectral densities. It is a wrapper function for `stats::spectrum` with some special options set.
- `spectrum` from `stats` allows you to choose the method used to estimate the spectral density: either periodogram or using autoregressive process.
- `cpgram` from `stats` plots a cumulative periodogram along with a confidence interval.

See, e.g., `?cpgram` or `?spectrum` for all the details and keep in mind that it is, e.g., `TSA::periodogram` and `GeneCycle::periodogram` when names of the functions coincide.

There are also plenty of examples and tutorials online on how to use those functions. See [here](http://homepage.univie.ac.at/erhard.reschenhofer/pdf/zr/Spec.pdf) for the usage of `fft` and [here](http://www.di.fc.ul.pt/~jpn/r/fourier/fourier.html) for an even more extensive tutorial.

Also, as you probably already know, a given time series must be detrended. Hence, use, e.g., `diff(x)` instead of `x`. And finally, the length of your time series must be divisible by 12 as to be able to identify 12 and 24 hours frequencies, it can be achieved by, e.g., `x[-(1:(length(x) %% 12))]`, where `x` is a detrended time series.

Answer (score 8):

Use `spectrum` to do a spectral density analysis; also `fft` for the base fast Fourier transform.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit. First do the fft on the original data, and then use the function spectrum?

Comment: no, `spectrum` is a self-contained spectral density analyzer; it calls `fft` with some pre- and post-processing and plotting.

Comment: The  two examples for fft do not window the data first.  Alas it is hard to find which libraries window data correctly without testing them with e.g. a ramp signal.  Test to make sure.