# Fast fourier transform in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm now developing a project in ruby on rails.

Is there anyway to calculate fft in ruby on rails?
Say retrieve some time domain raw data from database and do fft then out put the freq domain graph in web page.

Is there any gem support this calculation?

if not,is it possible to use ruby write calculate fft code? Or is there any other way of implementing this?

Comment: This may be helpful: https://github.com/corbanbrook/fourier_transform/blob/master/fourier_transform.rb

Comment: may be this will help you https://github.com/corbanbrook/fourier_transform

Comment: If you'd like to use [R](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R_(programming_language)), see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14010605/fast-fourier-transform-in-r) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10086605/best-way-to-use-r-in-ruby).